# SD of clusters (k-means)

Tags: r, cluster-computing, k-means, standard-deviation

I am trying to find out how to get SD of my clusters gain my k-means cluster analysis. 
I made the k-means and get several outputs, one of it are "centers" what I assume are means. I need standard deviations of all these centers to present my data and I don´t know, how to get them?

```
#kmeans
resultspoorT0t <- kmeans(poor_T0v, 3)
resultspoorT0t[["centers"]]

       ALH      BCF      LIN       VAP       VCL      VSL
1 5.130483 12.66909 40.14618  69.78680 146.97313 55.51221
2 3.098673 10.11618 34.38605  29.20927  69.74657 22.70321
3 7.212529 12.98836 41.71680 111.67745 229.73901 92.12502
```

I tried simple `sd()`function, but that makes one SD, I need SD for every parameter of every cluster

```
#SD
sd(resultspoorT0t$cluster, na.rm = FALSE)
[1] 0.758434
```

Comment: Thank you! I did that, hopefully in a right way :)

Comment: Normally one reports the total sum of squares, within sum of squares and between sum of squares and if `km` is the kmeans object then `str(km)` shows the names of the components which contain these values.

Comment: 'str' didn't show it, but thanks :)

Comment: Yes it does. Start a fresh session of R and try this:  `km <- kmeans(iris[1:4], 3); str(km)`  and you will see all the items I mentioned.  You can also just do `names(km)` to see just the names themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you want a simple circular SD. So you need to calculate the distance of each point from a cluster to the centre of that cluster. It is a Euclidian distance sqrt(sum((x_mean - x) ** 2 + (y_mean - y) ** 2 ...)). Then you can just calculate distances SD for each cluster. The code is:

```
# Some fake data
set.seed(2222)
df <- matrix(rnorm(6 * 50), 50)
colnames(df) <- letters[1:6]
df <- as.data.frame(df)
k_res <- kmeans(df, 3)

# SD = sd of points distances from cluster center
clusters <- k_res$cluster
centers <- k_res$centers


res_sd <- NULL
for (cl in c(unique(clusters))){
    df_part <- df[clusters == cl, ]

    # Calculate Euclidian distance between 
    # each point (row) and cluster center.
    dist <- sqrt(rowSums((df_part - centers[cl, ]) ** 2))

    # Calculate SD for each column (i.e. SD along each axis)
    sd_s <- apply(df_part - centers[cl, ], 2, sd)
    names(sd_s) <- paste("sd_", colnames(df_part), sep = "")

    res_part <- c(cluster = cl, total_sd = sd(dist), sd_s)
    res_sd <- rbind(res_sd, res_part)
}

res_sd <- as.data.frame(res_sd)
rownames(res_sd) <- res_sd$cluster
```

Comment: oki, I got stuck at a point of:
Error in df[clusters == cl, ] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
How can I fix it?

Comment: `df` should be your `poor_T0v`. It supposed to be a `data.frame`.

Comment: great. Now I got SD of individual clusters, but I need SDs of all parameters of what centers are shown for as well.
This is what I got

print(res_sd)
     cluster       sd
[1,]       1 53.47667
[2,]       2 24.18488
[3,]       3 98.47300

Is there some way, how to get all of the SDs?

Comment: Do you mean SD for each column per cluster?

Comment: So, is it what you need?

Comment: Yes! Perfect! that's it! Thank you very much!